# wordpress user registration payment

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, web, paypal

I need a plugin for wordpress that first takes a new user through paypal and then once the user pays, allows them to register for the website. I've tried pie-register but it first has the registration and then the payment and I don't want that.

I can build the plugin but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if there's already something out there like this.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you ever need to do that ? Having the registration before is normal, and you can simply let the account de-activated until the payment is confirmed.

Comment: I think you should stick to the real method. Let them register, then ask for the payment. When payment is successfully completed mark the user as active :)